# Handling versioning for a large Ruby project split into subprojects

Tags: ruby, project, versioning, packaging

**TL;DR** - *Large project has many plugins which cause automated tests to fail way too often. I’d like to split this project into a core repo and an extensions repo, but how?*

I have a large project ([nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/)) that has a plethora of plug-ins, each with their own dependencies. For example:

- A `handlebars` plugin, which depends on `therubyracer`
- A HTML validator plugin, which calls an external web service

A lot of these plugins occasionally fail:

- fail to build (e.g. `therubyracer` or `nokogiri`);
- produce output that is not expected by nanoc;
- call web services (e.g. HTML/CSS validator) that are down, throttling requests, etc.

The continuous integration service used by nanoc ([Travis](https://travis-ci.org/)) very regularly reports errors. 95% of these errors are caused by plugins.

This makes the continuous integration test results somewhat useless. I’ve grown to ignore “error” build statuses and just assume something went wrong in a plugin. This is clearly not a good situation.

I want to split up the project in two parts:

- a **core** repository+gem that contains the basic code for the project, without the plugins, and
- a **plugins** repository+gem that contains every single plugin.

I would work on *core* most of the time, occasionally updating the *plugins* repository so that it matches the work done in *core* (although usually, the changes in *core* will not affect *plugins*).

This seems like a reasonable approach, but I have some reservations:

- I have no good idea how to handle versioning. Should the same version be used for both gems, always? This may clash with the [Semantic Version](http://semver.org/) approach I am using now.
- Should there be a single plugins repository, or should each plugin get its own repository? This may make versioning even harder.
- I want to release new plugins quickly, so that people don’t have to wait for a new feature release before they can use the new plugins. Versioning is even more difficult here.

Thoughts and ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationship between plugins and main app.

If the plugin can only be used for this app only and there is a strong coupling, you need to put the plugin into plugin path and add it to main app repository.

If the plugin can be used for more general purpose and having less coupling, the better approach is to gemify these plugins as following:

1. Pull them out of main repo
2. Setup separate repo for each gem
3. Use custom gem path in Gemfile if you don't want to make them public.*